# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Iam doing a project on spring MVC with maven.Iam getting an error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource while running project.I include all the dependencies i think..below my codes.waiting for your reply

WEB.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
 <servlet-name>AccPerSpring</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>AccPerSpring</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"              xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

   <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
   <mvc:annotation-driven />


   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.gerrytan.pizzashop"/>
  <bean id="myDataSource" class=" org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
       <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
       <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"/>
       <property name="username" value="root"/>
       <property name="password" value="kca@fnpl#12"/>
 </bean>

     <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <bean id="mySessionFactory"class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
    <array>
     <value>com.gerrytan.pizzashop</value>
    </array>
   </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <value>
    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </value>
   </property>
   </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
   </bean>

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
   <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
   </beans>
```

pom.xml

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>AccPerSpring</groupId>
     <artifactId>AccPerSpring</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>war</packaging>

     <properties>
     <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
      <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
      </properties>

    <dependencies>
     <!-- Spring -->
         <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
     <version>${spring.version}</version>
   </dependency>

<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Java EE -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Others -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>

 </dependencies>

   <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1</version>
       <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
     </plugins>
     </build>
  </project>
```

Comment: Is this jar in your classpath commons-dbcp.jar ?? check

Comment: ya sure..but not working

Comment: commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4-javadoc.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4-sources.jar have these 3 jars

Comment: Are you deploying into Tomcat, by any chance?

Comment: I've just noticed you have a leading space in the "class" attribute of your declaration of the "myDataSource" bean.  I'll be surprised if this is the problem, but probably worth eliminating it just in case!

Comment: error has gone but still getting exception in console  (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource)

Comment: Show us your dependency tree (`mvn dependency:tree`).

Comment: Can you please make a copy of your jar file commons-dbcp and convert the extension to .zip(from .jar) and then open it up and see if the class being searched for is really there. We had a similar issue while using commons-dbcp2.jar. based on teh actual folder structure inside the jar/zip, we modified our datasources.xml entry to "org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" from "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" (notice the extra 2) - that solved the issue for us!

Answer (score 6):

Once the build completes check in your war file-> WEB-INF/lib for commons-dbcp-1.4.jar. If it is available in the class path then your issue will be solved. 
One more thing is, open your commons-dbcp-1.4.jar and check that particular class(org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource) is available or not? if not you have to try some other versions of commons-dbcp-1.4.jar.

Comment: 1.4 jar contain BasicDataSource class..then how

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you get these strange exceptions when you have conflicting versions of the same class.  This can happen because a different version of the same JAR is already on the application server's classpath, or if it's been included via a different dependency.

`mvn dependency:tree` is a command you can run to see all the dependencies that come into your application, including those that get brought in from other JARs.  It might be worth running this to check for other "dbcp" JARs that may be causing a conflict.

It's also worth checking your "lib" folder in the application server into which you're deploying to see if there's any "dbcp" JAR in there already.  If this is the case, then changing the scope to "provided" for the "commons-dbcp" artefact should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One common mistake could be importing class

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource

instead of

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

in your java code. It can be easily missed out, even in the error messages.